# Html canvas - Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'

Tags: html, internet-explorer

On this webpage I'm building there are a bunch of canvases and at a specific time I'm removing one of them with `canvas[0].remove()`. While this works very well in Chrome and Opera, it doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer and Safari. I get:

```
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'
```

Is there any solution to this?

Using IE11, Safari 5.1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a `childnode` [interface](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#childnode) :

> **node.before(nodes)** Inserts nodes just before node, while replacing
>   strings in nodes with equivalent Text nodes.
>
> Throws a `HierarchyRequestError` if the constraints of the node tree
>   are violated.
>
> **node.after(nodes)** Inserts nodes just after node, while replacing
>   strings in nodes with equivalent Text nodes.
>
> Throws a `HierarchyRequestError` if the constraints of the node tree
>   are violated.
>
> **node.replace(nodes)** Replaces node with nodes, while replacing
>   strings in nodes with equivalent Text nodes.
>
> Throws a `HierarchyRequestError` if the constraints of the node tree
>   are violated.
>
> **node.remove()** Removes node.

This is an experimental technology because this technology's specification has not stabilized. And it doesn't [implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove) in IE.

Use classic [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild):

```
canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas)
```